# RDS PostgreSQL 12.5 bind slow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-12

I have a PostgreSQL 12.5 db.r5.large instance on AWS RDS (16GB of RAM, 2 vCPU)
While I'm troubleshooting some slow queries, I have seen these in log quite often:

```
2021-07-28 12:31:14 UTC:172.21.12.81(57832):db@db:[23691]:LOG:  duration: 7111.815 ms  bind S_14: 
< ... query ...>
2021-07-28 12:31:14 UTC:172.21.12.81(57832):db@db:[23691]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '115', $2 = '115', $3 = '115', $4 = '115', $5 = '115', $6 = '115', $7 = '1234567', $8 = '2021-07-28 22:31:00.605+10'
2021-07-28 12:31:14 UTC:172.21.12.81(57832):db@db:[23691]:LOG:  execute S_14: 
< ... same query ...>
2021-07-28 12:31:14 UTC:172.21.12.81(57832):db@db:[23691]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '115', $2 = '115', $3 = '115', $4 = '115', $5 = '115', $6 = '115', $7 = '1234567', $8 = '2021-07-28 22:31:00.605+10'
2021-07-28 12:31:14 UTC:172.21.12.81(57832):db@db:[23691]:LOG:  duration: 0.296 ms
```

Looks like it took over 7s on `bind` and 0.296ms on `execute`
My question is:

- Is such behaviour normal?
- Is there a method to reduce time spent on `bind`?

EDIT:
Some more logs. There were other activities write and read activities at `2021-07-28 23:17:43` that I didn't include in this log

```
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '6d7f93d572c8fc12647da03bceced73d', $2 = '1.15233670737711'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute S_22: 
             INSERT INTO tsa (
              s_id, com_id, aii, di, st
             )
             VALUES (
              68088443, 56, $1, $2, '2021-07-28T23:17:26.088Z'
             ) ON CONFLICT (com_id, s_id, st, COALESCE(aii, '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')) DO UPDATE SET
              di = EXCLUDED.di
           
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '6d7f93d572c8fc12647da03bceced73d', $2 = '1.15233670737711'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.081 ms
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.383 ms  bind S_8: SELECT id, in_id, iid FROM m where com_id = $1 AND id IN ( $2 ) 
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '56', $2 = '9256d5c6f5426f26ea8d9f54129825b9'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute S_8: SELECT id, in_id, iid FROM m where com_id = $1 AND id IN ( $2 ) 
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '56', $2 = '9256d5c6f5426f26ea8d9f54129825b9'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.036 ms
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.062 ms  parse <unnamed>: 
              INSERT INTO tsf (
                s_id, com_id, e_id, iid, st
              )
              VALUES (
                68088443, 56, $1, $2, '2021-07-28T23:17:26.088Z'
              ) ON CONFLICT (com_id, st, e_id) DO NOTHING
              
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.047 ms  bind <unnamed>: 
              INSERT INTO tsf (
                s_id, com_id, e_id, iid, st
              )
              VALUES (
                68088443, 56, $1, $2, '2021-07-28T23:17:26.088Z'
              ) ON CONFLICT (com_id, st, e_id) DO NOTHING
              
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '76407529', $2 = '133397f31fd046faf1e92465276c85d1'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
              INSERT INTO tsf (
                s_id, com_id, e_id, iid, st
              )
              VALUES (
                68088443, 56, $1, $2, '2021-07-28T23:17:26.088Z'
              ) ON CONFLICT (com_id, st, e_id) DO NOTHING
              
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '76407529', $2 = '133397f31fd046faf1e92465276c85d1'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.135 ms
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.079 ms  parse <unnamed>: 
              DELETE FROM tsf tsf
              WHERE tsf.s_id = 68088443 AND tsf.com_id = 56
            AND e_id NOT IN ( SELECT in_id from m WHERE com_id = 56 AND id IN ('9256d5c6f5426f26ea8d9f54129825b9') )
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.689 ms  bind <unnamed>: 
              DELETE FROM tsf tsf
              WHERE tsf.s_id = 68088443 AND tsf.com_id = 56
            AND e_id NOT IN ( SELECT in_id from m WHERE com_id = 56 AND id IN ('9256d5c6f5426f26ea8d9f54129825b9') )
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
              DELETE FROM tsf tsf
              WHERE tsf.s_id = 68088443 AND tsf.com_id = 56
            AND e_id NOT IN ( SELECT in_id from m WHERE com_id = 56 AND id IN ('9256d5c6f5426f26ea8d9f54129825b9') )
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.218 ms
             
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.776 ms  bind S_9: 
              SELECT m.id, m.iid
              FROM m m
              LEFT JOIN tsf tsf
              ON tsf.e_id = m.in_id AND tsf.com_id = $1
              WHERE s_id = $2 AND m.com_id = $3
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '56', $2 = '12345443', $3 = '56'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute S_9: 
              SELECT m.id, m.iid
              FROM m m
              LEFT JOIN tsf tsf
              ON tsf.e_id = m.in_id AND tsf.com_id = $1
              WHERE s_id = $2 AND m.com_id = $3
             
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '56', $2 = '12345443', $3 = '56'
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.055 ms
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.027 ms  bind S_1: COMMIT
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  execute S_1: COMMIT
2021-07-28 23:17:43 UTC:172.21.12.81(55270):db@db:[9811]:LOG:  duration: 0.830 ms
2021-07-28 23:17:50 UTC:172.21.12.81(55190):db@db:[8188]:LOG:  duration: 7186.016 ms  bind S_8: 
              SELECT ts.in_id, ts.id, ts.com_id, ts.l_id, ts.hid, ts.cid, ts.st, ts.start_id,
                ts.end_time, (select m.id from m m where m.in_id = tsf.e_id AND m.com_id = $1), tsf.iid, ts.ide_id, ts.ide_alt, ts.last_updated, tsa.aii, tsa.di,
                pe.p_id, ts.is_co, ts.qual, ts.m_v, ts.em_v, ts.tem, ts.the_bl, ts.the_bl_source
              FROM ts ts
              LEFT JOIN tsa tsa ON tsa.s_id = ts.in_id AND tsa.com_id = $2 AND tsa.st = ts.st
              LEFT JOIN tsf tsf ON tsf.s_id = ts.in_id AND tsf.com_id = $3 AND tsf.st = ts.st
              LEFT JOIN te te ON te.track_id = ts.in_id AND te.com_id = $4
              LEFT JOIN pe pe ON pe.e_id = tsf.e_id AND pe.com_id = $5
              WHERE ts.com_id = $6 AND ( ts.in_id , ts.st ) IN ( ($7, $8) ) ORDER BY ts.st DESC 
2021-07-28 23:17:50 UTC:172.21.12.81(55190):db@db:[8188]:DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = '28', $2 = '28', $3 = '28', $4 = '28', $5 = '28', $6 = '28', $7 = '12345457', $8 = '2021-07-29 09:17:37.179+10'
```

**2nd EDIT**
We sort of "solved" this problem by adding a JDBC connection option `prepareThreshold=0`, although we do not know why. After adding this option, all prepared_statement in RDS log becomes `<unnamed>` but we don't observe any slow bindings anymore. We’d like to know why changing this option potentially solve this issue, too.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Waiting for object locks to be acquired is generally charged against the BIND's duration.  Do you have log_lock_waits set to on, and if so do you see any such waits being logged?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jjanes I enabled log_lock_waits and lock time is default 1s. Please see the updated logs. I don't see that bind is waiting for a lock though.